# Is there a Pythonic way to iterate over an "expanded" source list?

Tags: python

I created a generator expression that builds a dictionary out of more than the source keys, like so:

```
def moreIter(names):
    for name in names:
        yield name
        yield name + "Bar"

KEYS = ("a", "b")

src = {"a": 1, "aBar": 2, "b": 3, "bBar": 4, "c": 0, "cBar": 1, "d": 10}
d = {key: src[key] for key in moreIter(KEYS)}
```

I was wondering if there is a more "pythonic" way to do something like this. It seems all the standard library functions I've come across that iterate through a list will return something of an equal or smaller length than the original list, but in this case I want to iterate through an expanded result.

Comment: `itertools.chain()`?

Comment: The tuple of keys I care about is defined elsewhere in my current code, and could change, so really I want a way to convert it into an extended list with extra postfixes.

Perhaps itertools.chain() would work, I'm not too familiar with it... would it be something like this:

    itertools.chain(KEYS, a + "Bar" for a in KEYS, ...)

Comment: What is the actually problem you're solving? The example you've given ends up copying the `src` dict to the `d` dict. Can you give a more realistic example?

Comment: In my actual use case, I have a large dictionary, and a small set of keys, and to create a new dictionary from the large dictionary using the keys plus a certain set of related keys. So for each k in keys, I want the value from k, and the value from k + "Foo", and the value from k + "Bar", etc.

I'll edit the example to show that the source dict is actually larger than the dest.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a multi-level generator:

```
src = {"a": 1, "aBar": 2, "b": 3, "bBar": 4}
d = {key: src[key] for item in 'ab' for key in (item, item+'Bar')}
```

Comment: Thanks, I would not have thought of that! So there is a creative Python way to do it on one line. :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) in this case.  It really depends on how complex your *additive* keys will be:

```
from itertools import product

for name in map(''.join, product(['a', 'b'], ['', 'Bar'])):
    yield name

# ['a', 'aBar', 'b', 'bBar']
```

`product` generates a list of tuples

```
[('a', ''), ('a', 'Bar'), ('b', ''), ('b', 'Bar')]
```

Then `map` uses the `''.join` function to combine each tuple into a single string (you could use a list comprehension here instead of `map` but I think it makes it less readable because it's already in a `for` loop).

```
for name in (''.join(t) for t in  product(['a', 'b'], ['', 'Bar'])):
```

Answer (score 1):

For this question, moreIter(KEYS) return the keys of src. So:

```
>>> d = {k:src[k] for k in src.keys()}
>>> d
{'a': 1, 'aBar': 2, 'b': 3, 'bBar': 4}
```